# Why does the Color module in styled-components report an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, colors, styled-components

The environment I use is react + typescript, and the `@types/color` module has been installed. When I use `${props = > color（ props.theme.red ）}` Times error.

As follows:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colour from 'color';

const PercentUI = styled.p`
    color: ${(props) => colour(props.theme.red).darken(0.5)};
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
`;
```

report

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(props: ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>) => Color<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>'.
> Type '(props: ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>) => Color<...>' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>'.
> Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>'.
> Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.
> Types of property 'rotate' are incompatible.
> Type '(degrees: number) => Color' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | "none" | (string & {}) | "-moz-initial" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | undefined'.
> Type '(degrees: number) => Color' is not assignable to type '"unset"'.
> Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & object, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(props: ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>) => Color<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
> Type '(props: ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>) => Color<...>' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
> Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLParagraphElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & object, any>>'.
> Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.

What shall I do? T_T

Comment: You are using the wrong parameter, if you ask me. The last line: Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'. I don't know this method, but the `props.theme.red` does not match the parameter `colour()` is expecting. Second thought: the lambda is not the right type, which a "color" can take.

Comment: @JanosVinceller Your answer is very helpful to me. The hex and string methods of the color module can return the correct color format instead of the color object. Now there is no error in this way `${(props) => colour(props.theme.red).string()` Thanks♪(･ω･)ﾉ

Comment: You're welcome! You could give a "vote up" to my comment

Comment: @JanosVinceller I can't find the entrance to vote, is it because it's a comment rather than an answer? Or would you please answer it again? I'm a newcomer to stack overflow...

Comment: I'll vote for you